# RxJS: WebSocket reconnection handling

Tags: angular, websocket, rxjs

I've created a service to handle a WebSocket connection to send and receive messages, where I'm handling a few cases when a disconnection might happen and how to recover from them, but I'm missing the case where the browser itself (so to speak) goes offline it automatically retries when the `navigator.onLine` emits a `true` value again.

So far, by using the `retryWhen` operator, I'm able to create a new session and restart it (if something goes wrong on the server side), until it reaches a maximum number of retries.
But, by using the `navigator.onLine` (as unreliable as it is, I know, but it works for the browsers we are using) I can restart the reconnection process, when the client goes offline.

I have this online checker observable:

```
private onlineCheck: Observable<boolean>;

this.onlineCheck = merge(
      of(navigator.onLine),
      fromEvent(window, 'online').pipe(mapTo(true)),
      fromEvent(window, 'offline').pipe(mapTo(false)));
```

And this is how I'm creating a WebSocket (and handling a reconnection if needed):

```
public connect(): void {
  // no more than one connection simultaneously
  if (!(this.socket == null)) {
    this.socket.complete();
  }

  this.socket = new WebSocketSubject(this.config);
  this.socket
    .pipe(
      retryWhen((errors) => {
        return errors.pipe(
          tap((error) => { console.log('Error: ', error); }),
          concatMap((e, i) =>
            iif(
              () => i < this.reconnectAttempts,
              of(e).pipe(delay(this.reconnectInterval)),
              throwError('Max amount of retries reached')
            )));
      }))
    .subscribe(
      (message: MessageEvent) => { this.onMessage(message); },
      (error: Event) => { this.onError(error); },
      () => { console.log('completed'); });
  }
```

How can I combine an `onlineCheck` subscription with the `retryWhen` operator, in order to retry it, if the client went offline (and the maximum connection retries is reached) and is now back?
If this is not the best approach, could you please suggest another?

Here's a complete StackBlitz example (check the console logs for better feedback): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f4oa3y

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `iif` true condition, use this observable instead of `of(e).pipe(delay(this.reconnectInterval))`:

```
timer(this.reconnectInterval) // wait for reconnect interval
  .pipe(
    concatMap(() => onlineCheck),
    first(Boolean) // now wait for online to be true
  )
```

That will emit an observable that will produce a single value after reconnectInterval *and* onlineCheck is true

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I don't think this is working as expected. I even added a subscription somewhere else for `onlineCheck` and whenever `navigator.onLine` changes state, that subscription emits its new value, but this new retry flow you added, it does not.
As I mentioned on the question, there might be some scenarios where the `reconnectAttempts` will reach its maximum; that can actually happen if the `navigator.onLine` is `false`. So when it emits again a `true` value, it should retry again to connect the socket.